# How to run .exe program in fullscreen?

Tags: wine, games, fullscreen

I have a Chromebook and I want to play a game, a .exe file.
I followed some instructions I found online, I changed to developer so I can run Linux programs. I installed Wine and downloaded the game file, exported the file and opened it with Wine, all according to plan.
BUT when I open the game the window is really small, about a fourth of the screen. It doesn't work to use the fullscreen key on the keyboard and it doesn't work to change settings in wine.
Got any tips?

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details, what OS & release are you asking about?

Comment: Are you using the default Linux that comes with the Chromebook, or did you install Ubuntu? If issuing Ubuntu, which version?

Answer (score 0):

First way: Look at the game option after you run it using [Wine HQ](https://www.winehq.org/).

Second way: If the game hasn't option to make it full screen you have to use a program that called [Q4wine](https://sourceforge.net/projects/q4wine/), set the option for any size you like.